How do Unicode's ("Mathematical") "Flattened Parenthesis" and "Angle Bracket" symbols differ?
In UTF, "⟮" + "⟯" and "⟨" + "⟩" are distinct symbols of the "Miscellaneous Mathematical Symbols-A" block. The former are referred to as "Mathematical Flattened Parentheses", whereas the latter are "Mathematical Angle Brackets". I was under the impression that such terminology is interchangeable, but that appears to not be so in the mathematical context.
However, if that were so, I would expect a cursory Google search to be enough to inform me of the differences between them. It is not - there is not a single discussion of the differences between these symbols.
Can anyone enlighten me?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

@Shaun, some of the comments I've been notified of via e-mail appear to be absent from the chat, like https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5016425/how-do-unicodes-mathematical-flattened-parenthesis-and-angle-bracket-sy?noredirect=1#comment10759790_5016425 marking the duplicate. Were these deliberately excluded, or was the transferral accidentally incomplete?

They would deleted by the community bot, @RokeJulianLockhart, when the duplicate was confirmed.

Comment
This seems to be asking both about angle brackets like $\langle$ and $\rangle$ and about flattened parentheses like $\lgroup$ and $\rgroup$. It also might be asking about the intent of the Unicode specification of the "Miscellaneous Mathematical Symbols-A" block specifically, as opposed to merely how symbols that look like these are used in mathematics. (While it's recommended that a post only ask one question/about one thing, it seems that the OP genuinely felt/expected that these questions were related.)
Flattened Parentheses
Mathematics
While I'm not sure I've ever seen symbols like these before (at least not without realizing they weren't regular parentheses), so that I would consider them very rare, it appears they are typically or always intended to serve the same functions as regular parentheses.
They can be typed in $\TeX$ with \lgroup and \rgroup and Knuth's "The TeXbook" mentions

Notice that \lgroup and \rgroup are rather like bold parentheses, ... this makes them attractive for certain large displays.

A search of the internet for "\lgroup" yields many instances where they are used (or people are trying to use them) for standard parenthesis usages. For example:

grouping terms for the order of operations, as in $e^x\lgroup\dfrac1x+x\log x\rgroup$
a second level of grouping outside a pair of regular parentheses, as in
$\lgroup(1+kb)-(1+ky_m)e^{-k(y_m-b)}\rgroup$
function application (at least outside another function application), as in $f\lgroup h(t)\rgroup$
operator application, as in $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\lgroup\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\rgroup$ or $L^{-1}\lgroup\frac{1}{s^2-6s-10}\rgroup$

(I couldn't find an example of them being used for an ordered tuple like the coordinates of a point in space, but wouldn't be surprised if someone used them that way, too.)
Unicode
The reason for their inclusion in Unicode 5.1 in 2008 seems to be explained in Unicode's L2/07-011R (whose filename is "07011-n3198-math.pdf" and whose title is "Microsoft Word - N3198-AddMathChars-Draft4.doc").

In typesetting tall mathematical expressions, a special set of delimiters that look like
flattened parentheses are occasionally used. The chosen encoding model for large math
delimiters is to use the ordinary character code to select the type of delimiter and have the
layout software do the required stretching to scale the delimiter to the enclosed content.
The delimiters considered here are special, in that they have no ordinary-sized counterparts. In TeX, these delimiters can be selected with the \lgroup or \rgroup macros, but for
Unicode-based math layout, whether via MathML or other format, they cannot be used,
as there are currently no corresponding characters. Accordingly we propose [the addition of ⟮ and ⟯ ] with representative glyphs that look like scaled-down versions of the shapes in [an image from the TeXbook].

Angle Brackets
Mathematics
Angle brackets like $\langle$ and $\rangle$ have a lot of different uses in mathematics and related fields, all determined by context or an explicit definition in the text. I have attempted to collect them from various sources (neither Wikipedia's angle brackets in mathematics nor the relevant part of its glossary of mathematical symbols seems complete) here, but cannot dive deeply into examples or long explanations of each usage. They are used for:

ordered tuples/sequences (not necessarily of numbers), as in $\langle 1,2,3\rangle$. Sometimes, when discussing a Euclidean (affine) space, those tuples are distinguished (e.g. as vectors representing displacements) from other tuples written with parentheses (e.g. denoting points/positions) as in this MathSE answer to "Difference between parentheses and angle brackets in vector notation".
inner products of vectors (parentheses are sometimes used as well), such as $\langle \mathbf v,\mathbf w\rangle$ (or in Dirac notation, $\langle \mathbf v|\mathbf w\rangle$).
vectors (e.g. $|\phi \rangle$) and linear functionals (e.g. $\langle \phi|$) as well as with operators (as in $\langle \mathbf {r} |{\hat {A}}|\Psi \rangle$) in Dirac notation.
application of a linear functional in general (as in this and this other MathSE question)
generating objects in algebraic structures (parentheses are sometimes used as well), such as generating a subgroup of a group or an ideal of a ring. e.g. $\langle 10,16\rangle$ might denote the smallest ideal of the integers containing both $10$ and $16$ (which happens to be the even integers).
presentations of groups or similar, as in $\langle a\mid a^n=e\rangle$ or $\langle r,f\mid r^8,f^2,(rf)^2\rangle$
the ramp function as "Macaulay brackets" (primarily in continuum mechanics)
the expected value of some quantity (most often in Physics), as in $\langle S\rangle$ or $\langle V(t)\rangle$.
Sometimes, the expected value is not normalized, as mentioned in this MathSE question.
(Relatedly, $\langle\langle\cdot\rangle\rangle$ is sometimes used for
an atypical "average" defined in a physics paper.)
the quadratic variation as in this and this other MathSE question.
the set or sequence of nonegative integers below the input (extremely rare), e.g. $\langle N\rangle=\{0,1,\ldots,N-1\}$ from Benoit Boulet's "Fundamentals of Signals & Systems", quoted in this MathSE question.
as an alternative for curly braces when writing a set to make nesting levels clearer (very rare today), e.g. in Fraenkel's 1922 paper quoted in this MathSE question

There may be other niche uses I'm not familiar with and couldn't find on MathSE.
Unicode
The Unicode story of ⟨ and ⟩ (U+27E8 and U+27E9) seems a little complicated. There are non-mathematical punctuation uses of similar-looking symbols (U+3008 and U+3009) in East Asian languages like Japanese (as in 〈あ〉). And there were pre-existing angle brackets for math (namely 〈 and 〉, U+2329 and U+232A).
But apparently, according to L2/01-157 (whose filename is "01157-N2345R-brackets.pdf" and whose title is "Microsoft Word - n2345-brackets.doc"):

Unicode introduced a canonical mapping from 2329 to 3008 and from 232A to 3009. Although these canonical mappings should be seen as mistakes, at this time it is too late to change them. ... For a disunification, new single angle brackets/braces need[ed] therefore to be added.

And so new U+27E8 and U+27E9 were added to be reserved for the mathematical usages only. Wikipedia also mentions:

&lang; and &rang; were tied to the deprecated symbols U+2329 and U+232A in HTML4 and MathML2, but are being migrated to U+27E8 and U+27E9 for HTML5 and MathML3


This is incredible. I feel a mere thank isn't quite enough recompense for what amounts to a damn thesis.

Angle brackets are often used for inner products, as in
$$
\langle\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}\rangle
$$
Sometimes in old typed manuscripts, $<$ and $>$ were used instead, but they look bad.
The flattened parens are probably useful in expressions like
$$
(((3+4)(6+2(4-7)))+6)
$$
where the less-flat parens I've used here take up a good deal of horizontal space, but perhaps there's some other typographical use that I don't know of.
By the way, the "inner product brackets" are absolutely never used in grouping terms --- you'd never see
$$
\langle \langle 3 + 4 \rangle \langle 2 -6 \rangle \rangle
$$
Sometimes in elementary texts, square brackets and even braces are used to help distinguish levels of nesting, as in
$$
[ (3 + 4) (2 - 6) ]
$$
but by the time you reach algebra I, it's all parentheses, and square brackets are used for other stuff, and braces (i.e. { } ) are used primarily for sets.
